# How to find Android sdkmanager installed path in Windows with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-tools, registrykey, project-template

We are using Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.4 update) with Windows OS. We are facing issue on Android SDK manager installed path. Can you please suggest idea to get Android SDK manager installed path based on registry or command line?

Regards,
Dheepa

Answer (score 2):

To work with Android Visual Studio installs **openJDK** in

```sh
C:\Program Files\Android\jdk
```

and **Android SDK** at

```sh
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

You can find `sdkmanager.bat` at

```sh
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin
```

It is recommended to add the bin directory to the system path.

Comment: These paths do not exist after installing Android Studio 2022.3.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 1):

It should be in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android` unless you set a particular path. 
You won't have any key on the registry since it a folder from which VS (or any other IDE) "uses" the Android SDK. 
 You can give it a try checking in your Environment Variables if there is any path referring to the Android SDK, otherwise simply redownload the zip.